# is there a way in sql to use derived columns in SELECT statement to create more dependent columns without using temp tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have something like below for example. I think it is impossible to use the newly created `rowid` as a condition for a `case when` var or am I wrong? I could create a temp table but is there another way I can use `rowid` as a condition for a new `case when` variable, preferably without using temp tables?

```
select 
  * from (select ROW_NUMBER()OVER(partition by id ORDER BY id) as rowid ,
 case when rowid > 1 then 'a' else 'b' end as newvar
from tableA) as A
```

Comment: You can't reference columns by their alias in the same `SELECT`. You would need to define the column in a subquery or CTE first, and then reference it in the outer query/final `SELECT`.

Comment: the second question you referenced answered my question perfectly, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like below :

```
SELECT * FROM (
select CASE ROW_NUMBER()OVER(partition by id ORDER BY id) > 1 then 'a' else 'b' end as newvar
from tableA ) AS A
```